# Length of trim coming up wrong in audio trimming ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

So I have an application with a waveform that I can zoom in on.

I then open a trim control to edit the waveform.

The trim control starts out with a certain length when I hit the edit button, like so:

```
-(IBAction)edit:(id)sender {

if (player.duration) {

_trimControl = [[RETrimControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.waveform.frame.size.width, self.waveform.frame.size.height/4)];

_trimControl.length = player.duration*((self.waveform.zoomEndSamples-self.waveform.zoomStartSamples)/self.waveform.totalSamples);

_trimControl.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_trimControl];
[_trimControl setCenter:CGPointMake(self.waveform.center.x, self.waveform.center.y)];
}
}
```

This gives me the correct _trimControl.length.

However, when I try to reset the length after the user has zoomed in on the waveform, it give me the value of 0 for the exact same formula.

First I assign a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to my waveform view, so that when the user is done pinching on the waveform, an action happens like so:

```
-(void)pinchEnd:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer {
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && self.trimControl != nil) {

    [self resetTrim];
}
}
```

And the resetTrim method is as such

```
-(void)resetTrim {

_trimControl.length = player.duration*((self.waveform.zoomEndSamples-self.waveform.zoomStartSamples)/self.waveform.totalSamples);


NSLog(@"This is how many zoomEndSamples %lu", self.waveform.zoomEndSamples);
NSLog(@"This is how many zoomStartSamples %lu", self.waveform.zoomStartSamples);
NSLog(@"This is how many zoomTotalSamples %lu", self.waveform.totalSamples);
NSLog(@"This is how many seconds %f", player.duration);
NSLog(@"This is the trimcontrol %ld", (long)self.trimControl.length);
}
```

And this is the NSLog readout I get:

```
This is how many zoomEndSamples 2202964
This is how many zoomStartSamples 1046166
This is how many zoomTotalSamples 3249152
This is how many seconds 73.629025
This is the trimcontrol 0
```

What's strange is that if I take the values for all but the self.trimControl.length, the calculation comes out fine. It should definitely not be 0. And it wasn't zero in the edit IBAction above.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Why the self.trimControl.length is coming out differently?

UPDATE:

This is how I have my _trimControl declared in the ViewController.h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet RETrimControl *trimControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your instance variable, _trimControl, is nil. At first it holds and object, but for some reason it's being released.

Try logging that in both places:

```
NSLog(@"_trimControl = %@", _trimControl);
```

How is your trimControl property declared? Are you using ARC, or manual reference counting? If you're using manual reference counting and _trimControl is created as autoreleased, it could be released while the user is interacting with the user interface.

Update your question with more info on how you've defined your trimControl property and how you initialize it.

Comment: Added an update if that helped. Here is the NSLog I get in putting one at the bottom of the "edit" action and one just before everything happens in resetTrim:     _trimControl = <RETrimControl: 0x787934b0; frame = (0 67; 320 26); layer = <CALayer: 0x787818d0>>
2014-10-25 22:13:24.236 RecordPlay[5689:2021187] _trimControl = <RETrimControl: 0x787934b0; frame = (0 67; 320 26); layer = <CALayer: 0x787818d0>>

Comment: So much for my theory that _trimControl is nil then.